Turborepos not initializing new project
enter image description hereI,m trying to start a fresh project but can't as its showing this issue.
I reinstalled turbo and checked root node package.json file also but all in veins.It is saying package.json file not found but this file should be create by turbo but idk what is happening here can any one help me out.
